# How to set dynamic variable value to re.search method in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Below is my code.

```
mainfile = open('file2.txt', 'r')
tocheckfile = open('file1.txt', 'r')

mainList = []
toCheckList = []

for line in mainfile:
    mainList.append(line.upper().strip())

for line in tocheckfile:
    toCheckList.append(line.strip())

for line in mainList:
    got_line = line

for slave_line in toCheckList:
    if re.search(r'xxxxxx', slave_line):
        print(slave_line)
```

i want to add variable called got_line into the place of xxxxx. how can i do that thing?

Comment: `re.search(got_line, ..)`...!?

Comment: contains the last line of `file2.txt` a regular expression or just normal text? Or why do you use `re.search`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use regular expression for that check, you only want to know if the line in the input file is in the output file, right?
If so:

```
for line in mainList:
    for slave_line in toCheckList:
        if line in slave_line:
            print(slave_line)
```

would do it.

Mistakes in your code?
I don't know if you have some error on your identation or what, but the code

```
for line in mainList:
    got_line = line
```

will just assign the `got_line` variable to the las line of your input file.

Comment: actually i want to search is slave_line is exist somewhere in the line because line is getting very long string and slave_line is getting small value.

Comment: what? If you want to find if slave line exists in the original line, then just flip the condition `if slave_line in line`